# Apache shows it works page even if i change the path of document root

Tags: windows, wordpress, apache, ubuntu-server

My Probleme, is when i put **wordpress.local.fr**, to display welcome page of my wordpress, it shows me always it works page.

[image]

but when i make  **wordpress.local.fr/wordpress** it works

[image]

and this is what i have done :

Ip  Adresse of ubuntu server : 192.168.52.130

### In etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin wordpress.local.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

### etc/hosts :

```
192.168.52.130 wordpress.local.fr
# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

### hosts windows :

```
192.168.52.130 wordpress.local.fr
```

wordpress folder contain all my files there is no children folder and i have used **samba** to share /var/www/ between windows and ubuntu server

```
[Share]
  comment = Shared
  path    = /var/www/
  browseable = yes
  read only = no
  guest ok = yes
  writeable = yes
```

I don't know where I am going wrong.
what can i check and change ?

### Edit

I have tried to make just a txt file in fileindex folder instead my wordpress project and making in DocumentRoot /var/www/fileindex always i have the it works page so the DocumentRoot  is not taken into account

### my htaccess file (in my wordpress/ folder) it was :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# END WordPress
```

I have edited my htaccess file (in my wordpress/ folder). to that :

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

I have changed my serverAdmin to serverName like that :

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wordpress.local.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/wordpress/
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

after restarting my apache it still the same probleme

Thanks by advance

Comment: Have you restarted Apache after making your changes?

Comment: Yes i have restarted my apache, it existe another file that it has also document root ? or only in sites-available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your config I'm seeing

```
ServerAdmin wordpress.local.fr
```

ServerAdmin directive is for emails to receive when Apache hits error, it should be

```
ServerName wordpress.local.fr
```

Comment: thank you ... i have made edit to my config after restarting my apache but it still the same probleme

Comment: Your browser caches, try clearing cache and reload the page

Comment: Ooops! Your file is in 

etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress

Its not enabled yet, create a symbolic link to enabled directory

`sudo ln /etc/apache2/sites-available/wordpress /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/wordpress`

Comment: It works thank you so mush !!!!!!! one question can we use also sudo mv instead sudo ln ...

Comment: Yup, but symbolic links are okay for it

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you need to update your `.htaccess` file (in your `wordpress/` folder).

Change `RewriteBase` from `/` to `/wordpress/`.

Have fun!

Comment: My .htaccess file in my wordpress/ folder contain this # BEGIN WordPress

# END WordPress
how i can update that ?

Comment: i have tried to make just a txt file in fileindex folder instead my wordpress project and making in DocumentRoot /var/www/fileindex always i have the it works page thank you for your answer